# Comparar Fechas PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente query en mi BD MYSQL, donde lo que hago es mostrar el ID y las fecha de inicio de alguna solicitud ingresada en mi sistema.

```
SELECT id_formulario_1, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_solicitud, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_solicitud
FROM servicio_de_salud where id_formulario_1 = $fecha_inicio
```

Lo que me gustaría hacer pero desconozco como hacerlo, es realizar la misma consulta pero que compare entre la fecha de inicio y la fecha actual en el servidor. Si la fecha de inicio es menor en 2 semanas que me la muestre, esto lo necesito para visualizar todas las solicitudes que se acercan a la fecha actual y deben ser cursadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me da la impresión que hay un error en la cláusula WHERE. Donde pone id_formulario_1 = $fecha_inicio debería poner fecha_solicitud = $fecha_inicio.

No obstante, para obtener el resultado que buscas te podrían servir las siguientes consultas:

```
SELECT id_formulario_1, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_solicitud, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_solicitud FROM servicio_de_salud WHERE (fecha_solicitud + INTERVAL 2 WEEK) > NOW();
```

o utilizando la condición BETWEEN:

```
SELECT id_formulario_1, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_solicitud, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_solicitud FROM servicio_de_salud WHERE fecha_solicitud BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sería con `INTERVAL 2 WEEK` pero ten cuidado porque si lo subes a un hosting en ocasiones no te da la misma hora de tu máquina.

```
SELECT id_formulario_1, DATE_FORMAT(fecha_solicitud, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha_solicitud
FROM servicio_de_salud WHERE (fecha_solicitud + INTERVAL 2 WEEK) > NOW()
```